# Build to multiple build servers on a single Gitlab merge request?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I need some direction here.  I'm reading whatever documentation I can find online but it's not hitting the right synapses or I haven't found the right link yet.  On a merge request to a deployable environment, I want to kick off a build on two separate machines.  Both machines are IBM Is, running different versions of the OS.  I'd like for these builds and subsequent deploys to happen independently of each other.

My .yml file has the entries for the build for the two machines (QQDEV & BNADEV), but the builds occur sequentially, not in parallel.  The picture below is what Gitlab draws.

[image]

To me, from the above picture, it looks like both build_BNADEV and build_QQDEV are going to run the deploy jobs DEV_BNADEV and DEV_QQDEV.  I want build_BNADEV to run DEV_BNADEV, et al, and that is a separate issue aside from the parallel builds.

What do I need here?  Another runner?  Another pipeline?  Just looking for general pointers and direction here.

Here is my YAML.

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_QQDEV:
  variables: 
    THING: "This is a THING for build for QQDEV"
  script:
    - "bash ./GitLabCI/GitLabCI.Build.sh qqdev"
  stage: build
  only:
    - DEV
    - QA
    - UAT
    - PROD

build_BNADEV:
  variables: 
    THING: "This is a THING for build for BNADEV"
  script:
    - "bash ./GitLabCI/GitLabCI.Build.sh bnadev"
  stage: build
  only:
    - DEV
    - QA

DEV_QQDEV:
  variables: 
    THING: "This is a THING for deploy_DEV_QQDEV"
    ASPGRP: "*NONE"
  script:
    - "bash ./GitLabCI/GitLabCI.Deploy.sh QQDEV EPDEV1_5 /home/quikq/1.5/dev"
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: DEV
  only:
    - DEV

DEV_BNADEV:
  variables: 
    THING: "This is a THING for deploy_DEV_BNADEV"
    REBUILD_DEPLOYMENT: "0"
    ASPGRP: "DATADEV"
  script:
    - "bash ./GitLabCI/GitLabCI.Deploy.sh BNADEV EPDEV1_5 /home/quikq/1.5/dev"
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: DEV
  only:
    - DEV

QA_QQDEV:
  variables: 
    THING: "This is a THING for deploy_QA_QQDEV"
    ASPGRP: "*NONE"
  script:
    - "bash ./GitLabCI/GitLabCI.Deploy.sh QQDEV EPQA1_5 /home/quikq/1.5/qa"
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: QA
  only:
    - QA

QA_BNADEV:
  variables: 
    THING: "This is a THING for deploy_QA_BNADEV"
    REBUILD_DEPLOYMENT: "0"
    ASPGRP: "DATADEV"
  script:
    - "bash ./GitLabCI/GitLabCI.Deploy.sh BNADEV EPQA1_5 /home/quikq/1.5/qa"
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: QA
  only:
    - QA

UAT_QQ:
  variables: 
    THING: "This is a THING for deploy_UAT_QQ"
    ASPGRP: "*NONE"
  script:
    - "bash ./GitLabCI/GitLabCI.Deploy.sh QQ EPUAT1_5 /home/quikq/1.5/uat"
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: UAT
  only:
    - UAT

UAT_QQBNA:
  variables: 
    THING: "This is a THING for deploy_UAT_QQBNA"
    ASPGRP: "*NONE"
  script:
    - "bash ./GitLabCI/GitLabCI.Deploy.sh QQBNA EPUAT1_5 /home/quikq/1.5/uat"
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: UAT
  only:
    - UAT

PROD_QQ:
  variables: 
    THING: "This is a THING for deploy_PROD_QQ"
    ASPGRP: "*NONE"
  script:
    - "bash ./GitLabCI/GitLabCI.Deploy.sh QQ EPPROD1_5 /home/quikq/1.5/prod"
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: PROD
  only:
    - PROD

PROD_QQBNA:
  variables: 
    THING: "This is a THING for deploy_PROD_QQBNA"
    ASPGRP: "*NONE"
  script:
    - "bash ./GitLabCI/GitLabCI.Deploy.sh QQBNA EPPROD1_5 /home/quikq/1.5/prod"
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: PROD
  only:
    - PROD
```